# ASP GridView Calculated column

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I Need to check your views on following.

I have a grid which has a calculated columns. The calculation is done using `(Col A - col B) / SomeLabelAtTopofPage.Text`

Question - Is it a good practice to have these calculation done in the grid declaration? (I personally do not like it, I like to keep my ASPX as clean as possible)

Example:

`<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Calculated Column" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
        <ItemTemplate>
             <span><%# (double.Parse(Eval("A").ToString()) -                                               double.Parse(Eval("B").ToString())) / double.Parse(SomeLabelAtTopofPage.Text) %></span>
        </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>`

Or is it better to do it in the `DataBound` Event of the grid?

`var calcVal = ((Convert.ToDouble(e.Row.Cells[2].Text) - Convert.ToDouble(e.Row.Cells[3].Text)) / Convert.ToDouble(SomeLabelAtTopofPage.Text)) * 100;`

`e.Row.Cells[12].Text = string.Format("{0:0.000%}", calcVal);`

I would rather do this at the source that is the stored procedure, but for some reasons I cannot modify the proc.

Can anyone guide me, on what would be a better way to do this and why?

Thank You

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is right place for these types of question

Comment: Thank you Satinder.I will move the question there.

Comment: grid view Data Bound is the good choice

Comment: And why would that be? Could you please explain?